# postgreSQL LEFT and UPPER interaction

Tags: sql, postgresql

Question: Write a query that returns the name, address, state, and zipcode from all purchases.
For the names, return only the first 5 characters, and display them in all uppercase letters, sorted in alphabetical order.

Code so far:

```
SELECT LEFT (name, 5) AS UPPER, address, state, zipcode
FROM purchases
ORDER BY name;
```

I'm at a loss of where and how to use UPPER to capitalize all the characters in the first column that is being returned. So far this is 9/10 checks passed for my code.

Comment: upper is function. Here you rename  field as upper. `SELECT UPPER(LEFT(name,5)) ...` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add upper function  in your query

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT('JOhNdOEISMYNAME', 5)) AS UPPER
```